# Creation and annihilation operators in the hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, atomic-physics, hydrogen, quantum-chemistry

In my quantum chemistry course, we have been discussing the wavefunctions of the hydrogen atom, further, I am familiar with the idea of ladder operators from the quantum harmonic oscillator. Can we use ladder operators to jump between orbitals in a hydrogen atom? It appears from a cursory check that $$ \hat a^+ \psi_{1s} \neq \psi_{2s} $$ such that $$\hat a^+ = \frac{-i}{\sqrt{2w \hbar}}(\hat P+iw \hat X)$$ Is there any such set of ladder operators such that the above relation would be true? Thanks, and I apologize in advance if this question is naive. (Further, I am asking about ONLY wavefunctions of the solved hydrogen atom)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is set of ladder operators for the discrete spectrum of the Hydrogen atom, too. Following [Fitts](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed072p1066), we can set the variables of the radial equation so that this is exactly as:

$$\left(\rho^2 \frac{d^2}{d\rho^2} + 2\rho\frac{d}{d\rho}+\lambda\rho-\frac{\rho^2}{4}\right)S_{\lambda l}=l(l+1) S_{\lambda l} \tag{1}.$$

Then the sought ladder operators are defined as:

$$ \hat{A}_{\lambda} := \rho\frac{d}{d\rho}+\frac{\rho}{2}-\lambda \tag{2},$$
$$ \hat{B}_{\lambda} := \rho\frac{d}{d\rho}-\frac{\rho}{2}+\lambda \tag{3}.$$

By using the operators in (2) and (3) to rewrite (1), one can show that $\hat{A}_{\lambda}+\hat{1}$ is a lowering ladder operator (in $\lambda$), and $\hat{B}_{\lambda}+\hat{1}$ is a raising ladder operator (also in $\lambda$).

For the rest of the algebraic treatment, see the quoted article by Fitts or [his textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DM26RKO), which is based on his article, just with minor changes.

Just in case the article and book are out of reach, here are the definitions:

The radial equation from textbooks is:

$$\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\frac{d R(r)}{dr}\right) +\left[\frac{2\mu}{\hbar^2}\left(E+\frac{Ze^2}{r}\right)-\frac{l(l+1)}{r}\right]R(r) =0 \tag{4}.$$

To get (1), we need to define as follows (remember, $E<0$):

$$ \lambda :=\frac{\mu Z e^2}{\hbar \sqrt{-2\mu E}} \tag{5}, $$

$$ \rho := 2\frac{\sqrt{-2\mu E}}{\hbar} r = \frac{2\mu Z e^2}{\lambda \hbar^2} r = \frac{2Z}{\lambda a_{\text{Bohr}}} \tag{6}, $$

$$ a_{\text{Bohr}} := \frac{\hbar^2}{\mu e^2} \tag{7},$$

$$ R_{El} (r) =: \left(\frac{2Z}{\lambda a_{\text{Bohr}}} \right)^{3/2} S_{\lambda l}(\rho) \tag{8}.$$